# Como e quando criar packages no Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Estou há dias pesquisando e pensando sobre um assunto e ainda não entendi como fazer/usar/começar:

### Cenário

- Package: Livros (crud)
- Package: Módulo Autenticação (usuários + perfis + login + permissão)

### Dúvida

Tenho 2 packages, porém o packaeg **Livros** pertence a (belongsTo) Usuário: **como eu faço isso?**

1. Como eu configuro esse relacionamento? **(pacotes distintos)**
2. Como eu configuro a **dependência** de um pacote? (Livro dependente de usuário para funcionar corretamente)
3. E se não existir o package de autenticação e sim os arquivos padrões na pasta APP, como eu relaciono com o package de Livros?
4. Livros e Autenticação realmente necessitam ser packages? Ou seja: esse é o real conceito de packages? pequenos módulos, 1 biblioteca qualquer (upload por exemplo), etc)

---

É mais uma dúvida conceitual do que prática, mas eu gostaria de saber na prática também como efetuar os relacionamentos.

Se precisarem de mais informações me avisem.

Obrigado!

Comment: Bem no meu entendimento, Livros e Usuários são **Entidades** da sua aplicação, e não dos pacotes. Seu package na verdade seria somente o Crud e o Módulo de Autenticação, onde eles consomem a entidade (ou o Model).

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia!

Se eu entendi bem quais eram suas dúvidas:

Os relacionamentos, em laravel, ficam armazenados nas models.

Model Book, por exemplo:

```
public function user()
{
    $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Se desejar que o relacionamento seja chamado toda fez que recuperar um ou mais livros do banco de dados, pode utilizar o atributo with da model Eloquent\Model:

```
protected $with = ['user'];
```

onde 'user' é o nome dado no método acima.

Laravel tem um ótimo gerenciamento de permissões, então você poderia definir mais regras na model User, como:

public function isAdmin()
{
    return ($this->isAdmin == true);
}

Assim você pode verificar se o usuário é admin em qualquer local da aplicação, apenas chamando:

Auth::user()->isAdmin()

Seguindo o mesmo cursos poderá fazer validações mais complexas e flexivéis utilizando uma tabela para armazenar as regras ou grupos também.

Exemplo de gerenciamento de permissões utilizada pelo Django em sqlite, sem as restrinções:

```
CREATE TABLE `auth_user` (
    `id`    integer NOT NULL,
    `password`  varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `last_login`    datetime NOT NULL,
    `is_superuser`  bool NOT NULL,
    `group_id`  integer NOT NULL,
    `username`  varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `first_name`    varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    `is_active` bool NOT NULL,
    `date_joined`   datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `auth_permission` (
    `id`    integer NOT NULL,
    `name`  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `content_type_id`   integer NOT NULL,
    `codename`  varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `auth_group_permissions` (
    `id`    integer NOT NULL,
    `group_id`  integer NOT NULL,
    `permission_id` integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `auth_group` (
    `id`    integer NOT NULL,
    `name`  varchar(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Desse modo você poderia realizar um [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

para determinar se um usuário possui a permissão para acessar determinado local, juntamente com a adição de filtros que façam isso automaticamente.

Os pacotes tem o objetivo de deixar o projeto mais organizado, flexível e reutilizável, de forma que você possa utiliza-los em outras aplicações sem muitas alterações. Seu uso não é necessário, mas recomendado para grandes aplicações.

Ao invés de construir pacotes, poderia criar uma pasta dentro de /app chamada biblioteca e adicionar ao composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "Biblioteca": "app/biblioteca"
        }
    },
```

Em cada script dentro desta pasta, deve-se se utilizar a separação por namespace.

Um bom exemplo é o código aberto do [laravel-tricks](https://github.com/CodepadME/laravel-tricks).

Comment: agradeço a sua resposta. Mas minha questão é mais teórica mesmo: quando criar pacotes? baseado em que? E fora isso (um pouco técnico), como relacionar 2 pacotes? (dependências, models, etc)